# ProxyPass on Nginx not working as expected

Tags: fedora, nginx, python3, reverse-proxy

I've been trying for a while to get a Python (Sanic) application working with Nginx. The application itself is running on `0.0.0.0:5000`. The server is on a local network and only used to host/serve the projects. We have a main (public facing) web server that we reverse proxy each project in. To that extent the server running the Python application doesn't have a domain name since it doesn't serve projects directly (our proxy server does have a domain name and is publicly accessible). In the proxy server I just reference the host servers from their local IP. This method has worked for several of our other servers (Apache based), but we acquired this one fairly recently and I wanted to give Nginx a shot.

For context I did try Apache, but I was not able to get it working so I suspect there might be an underlying issue I am missing. I just want to check that my `nginx.conf` makes sense (since I am fairly new to Nginx) and to see if anyone has any suggestions as to what could be giving me trouble.

Final piece of context. I can access the service locally on the project host machine by doing `curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/my_app` or `curl http://(machine’s-local-ip):5000/my_app`; note that I have to specify the port else it doesn't work. From the proxy server I can only access the project host machine by doing `curl http://(machine’s-local-ip)/`, which returns the default Nginx html response. Any attempt to communicate with the endpoint `/my_app` results in a `50X error`.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        location /my_app/ {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/my_app/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Host "machine’s-local-ip";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you’re saying that you have a public-facing web server that doesn’t have a domain name.   I guess that you could do this by publicizing the IP address, but that’s fairly impractical.   If that’s not what you meant, please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

So after some more investigation and looking at the nginx logs, it turns out it was a SELinux issue. Following the steps at http://alfredoroca.github.io/nginx/selinux/2017/03/13/Allowing-Nginx-to-use-a-Puma-Unicorn-UNIX-socket-with-SELinux fixed the issue. I'll post them below for completeness.

```bsh
$ sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx > nginx.te
$ cat nginx.te
```

```
# cat output
# require {
#     type unconfined_t;
#     type httpd_t;
#     type httpd_sys_content_t;
#     class sock_file write;
#     class unix_stream_socket connectto;
#     class capability2 block_suspend;
# }
#
# ============= httpd_t ==============
# allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:sock_file write;
# allow httpd_t self:capability2 block_suspend;
# allow httpd_t unconfined_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

```bsh
$ checkmodule -M -m -o nginx.mod nginx.te
$ semodule_package -o nginx.pp -m nginx.mod
$ sudo semodule -i nginx.pp
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```